# how can I adjust my constraints so that my UITextView appears only when user scrolls the UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

There is a project on github about growing `UITextView` here https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView I downloaded it to my `swift` app and followed the instructions on their page.

This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {


    let textView = GrowingTextView()
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0
    textView.maxLength = 200
    textView.maxHeight = 70
    textView.trimWhiteSpaceWhenEndEditing = true
    textView.placeHolder = "Say something"
    textView.placeHolderColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)
    textView.placeHolderLeftMargin = 5.0
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)

    inputToolbar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Send
    inputToolbar.addSubview(textView)
    let views = ["textView": textView]
    let hConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-8-[textView]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    let vConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-8-[textView]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    inputToolbar.addConstraints(hConstraints)
    inputToolbar.addConstraints(vConstraints)
```

This `UITextView` is placed below the `UITableView`:

[image]

The `UIBottomBar` has 4 constraints: `leading`, `trailing`, `bottom` and `top` where `top` is equals to `UITableView` bottom.

The `UITableView` also has 4 constraints: `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom` where `bottom` is equals to `UIBottomBar` top.

I also connected IBOutlet to the `bottom` constraint of `UIBottomBar` and I'm modifying it in the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
    let endFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    bottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) - endFrame.origin.y
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Everything works pretty well. 
I need to introduce here a change - the `textView` is hidden when the `UITableView` is scrolled to the top. But when user starts scrolling it - `textView` appears and works as it should - grows with every new line of text.

I thought about using method `scrollViewDidScroll` on my `UITableView`, but I don't know how to adjust specific constraints there.

This is what I so far have:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 100) {


    }else {


    }
}
```

now I need to include constraint changes in this `if-else` statement. Can you help me with that?

Comment: bit of complicated, Please clear here that Do you want to hide textview when tableview is scrolling?

Comment: @SatishMavani when user opens the panel and table is visible from top then the `textview` should be hidden. It should appear when user starts scrolling down

Comment: I tried with putting `textView.hidden = true` in the `if` statement, but then even though the `textView` is hidden - the `uitableView` is not stretched to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Set constraint for the height of your textview and make it 0 instead of hiding it/.
OR
If textview is subview of some other view then set height constraint of that superview only.

Comment: I attached a height constraint to the `textView` and set it up to `0` in viewDidLoad. Then in my `if-else` I'm setting it `textViewConstraint.constant = 0` and in else: `textViewConstraint.constant = 44`. But when I do that it does not grow when user inputs more text...

Comment: In my code there's this line `let hConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-8-[textView]-8-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)` and it sets the constraint from the code. Could you help me with changing it so that first it is equal to 0 and then changes to `"H:|-8-[textView]-8-|"` when user scrolls?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should set height constraint to the super view of textview, and set top and bottom constraint 0 of textview.

Then you will have to increase height of your super view dynamically on text did change delegate method of textview

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];

    if (newSize.height>133)
        self.containerCiewHeightConstraints.constant=153;
    else if (newSize.height<36){
        self.containerCiewHeightConstraints.constant=50;
    }
    else
        self.containerCiewHeightConstraints.constant=newSize.height+18;

}
```

Here containerCiewHeightConstraints is constraint of my super view and 50 and 133 are min and max height of my textview